# Symlinked systemd script not starting at boot without daemon-reload

Tags: systemd

I have a custom systemd service in CentOS 7 whose startup script lives under version control at `/srv/etc/systemd/website.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=website
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=website
ExecStart=/opt/perl5/perls/perl-5.20.2/bin/hypnotoad /var/www/domains/<domain>/script/site.pl
ExecStop=/opt/perl5/perls/perl-5.20.2/bin/hypnotoad --stop /var/www/domains/<domain>/script/site.pl

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I run `systemctl enable /srv/etc/systemd/website.service` it creates the symlinks fine and I can run `systemctl start website` and the service comes up, but it complains about a missing [Install] section, which clearly isn't correct:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable /srv/etc/systemd/website.service 
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/website.service to /srv/etc/systemd/website.service.
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

After rebooting, the service does not come up, and a `systemctl start website` returns `Failed to start website.service: Unit not found`. If I run `systemctl daemon-reload`, the `start` command works again.

However, if I *copy* the file into /etc/systemd/system and run `systemctl enable website`, everything works as expected and the service comes up immediately after reboot.

Is it actually possible to do what I'm trying to do, or do I just need to live with remembering to manually copy the systemd script from my Git repo if I make any changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check to see if the drive that the symlink is referring to is mounted at the time the services are starting.

Comment: Facepalm. It turns out that's exactly the issue, thanks!